# How can I use SaveMode.Ignore when writing with Spark, in the all partition levels?

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I save a DataFrame with Spark, in S3, and partition it by `id`, `dt`, and `tm` -

```
rawData.coalesce(5000)
       .write
       .partitionBy("id", "dt", "tm")
       .mode(SaveMode.Ignore)
       .parquet(outputPath)
```

I will get something from the following structure in my bucket -

```
|id=1|dt=2022-10-01|tm=01
|    |             |tm=02
|    |dt=2022-10-02|tm=01
|    |             |tm=02
|    |             |tm=03
|id=2|dt=2022-10-01|tm=01
|    |             |tm=02
|    |             |tm=03
|    |dt=2022-10-02|tm=01
|    |             |tm=02
|    |             |tm=03
```

This process runs every day, and `rawData` is data I read from a different location, where the whole data is placed, and I filter only the columns and ids I need and save it to my bucket.

I want the `SaveMode.Ignore` mode to check the data in the partition levels so that it will check either `id`, `dt`, and `tm`.

Is it possible? Maybe with other tools of Spark? Or should I manage it by myself?
I formulate it as a question for a specific case, but it is actually the requirement of every efficient and legitimate ETL process.